# How to case handle a field in Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group the below CTE based on StudentID and I would like to compute the result with a rule like, if he passes in one subject he is passed overall , if not failed.

```
WITH mycte(StudentId,SubjectId,Result) as
  (SELECT 1,1,'pass'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,'fail'
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,3,'pass'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'fail'
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,'fail'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,NULL
   )
```

Can you help me in understanding how to achieve this logic.

Expected Result is like

```
StudentID Result
1         pass
2         fail
3         NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate over students and count the number of passes.  According to your logic, if even one pass is seen then the student should be reckoned as passing overall.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.StudentId,
    t2.Result
FROM mycte t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        StudentId,
        CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'pass'
             WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
             THEN 'fail'
             ELSE NULL END AS Result
    FROM mycte
    GROUP BY StudentId
) t2
    ON t1.StudentId = t2.StudentId
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I guess I have not written the question clear. I have updated the question with expected results. The query you have provided, qualifies just the passed student.

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple way

```
SELECT StudentId,
       Result = Max(Result)
FROM   mycte
GROUP  BY StudentId
```

Trick here is `Pass` will be ordered after `Fail` in string ordering. So when you use `Max` aggregate we will get `Pass` if at least one `Pass` is present

Comment: Nice thing Radheep.